# Rails and date_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, select

I am trying to use date_select with some of my forms.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :begin_date %>
  <br/>
  <%= f.date_select(:begin_date,:start_year => Time.now.year) %>
</div>
```

Reading through the documentation, I was expecting to get three select tags. What I got was: begin_date(1i), begin_date(2i), begin_date(3i)

If I include these in my model:

```
attr_accessible :begin_date(1i), :begin_date(2i), :begin_date(3i),
```

The IDE does not like it. What am I doing wrong? Also, is there a date select method that would return the values in a single tag, instead of 3?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `attr_accessible :begin_date`, and it will stitch together the date components into a single `Date` value for you.

Comment: That's not the issue. In my question, I've already specified that I'm using: attr_accessible :begin_date(1i), :begin_date(2i), :begin_date(3i) but the IDE(RuhbyMine) does not like the parenthesis

Comment: You don't need those multiple attr_accessible calls, try it with just `attr_accessible :begin_date`, no parentheses.

Comment: After experimenting with it a bit, it turns out that once I kept :begin_date in the model, it automatically assembled the various pieces for me as :begin_date